# Переход на фрагмент вне BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть примерно такая планировка экранов

```
- BottomNavigationView
  + home
  + list
  + profile
+ details
+ create
```

мне нужно сделать переход с home -> create, list->details

единственное решение которое приходит на ум это deepLink

Насколько это правильно и есть ли более оптимальное решение?

Comment: уточните более подробно что планируется по итогу? deep_link используется для навигации по приложению, но что-то мне кажется оно вам не нужно для вашей задачи. Можно сделать обычые фрагменты/dialog_fragment с возвратом на основную навигацию

Comment: в приложении навигация производится с помощью графа и экшонов, но мне нужно сделать переход на фрагмент который находится вне графа BottomNavigationView, я бы мог для этого использовать deepLink но сомневаюсь что это хороший вариант

Answer (score 0):

Deeplink кажется не лучшим решением.
Думаю адекватнее всего граф, который внутри **BottomNavigationView** сделать Nested(вложенным) внутри основного графа.

[Подробнее про вложенные графы](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs)

Далее добавить global action и использовать его для навигации.

[Подробнее про глобальные экшны](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action)

Думаю вопросов возникнуть не должно, но если что могу подробнее описать процесс.